How do i call the function as a parameter
I m new to programming i have stored the two function getComputerChoice() and getPlayerChoice()  in a variable so that i can place them in the function playround parameter. but the value of the two is undefined in the playround. what am i doing wrong.
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
const playerSelection = getPlayerChoice();

let playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {

    const playerWin = `You win, you choose ${playerSelection} and the computer picked ${computerSelection}`;
    const computerWin = `You loose, you choose ${playerSelection} and the computer picked ${computerSelection}`
    const draw = `Ohhhhhhh, a drawww , You choose ${playerSelection} and the computer picked ${computerSelection}`;

    if (playerSelection == computerSelection && computerSelection == playerSelection) {
        return draw; 
    } else if (playerSelection > computerSelection && computerSelection < playerSelection) {
        return computerWin; 
    } else if (playerSelection < computerSelection && computerSelection > playerSelection) {
        return playerWin; 
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

I am  unable to find any solution

Where do you ever call playRound and do you pass those variables to it?  That function defines local variables of the same name as the ones you've defined outside of the function.  So those local ones will have the values of whatever you pass to the function call.

You don't need to compare things twice. A = B is the same as B = A. Likewise A > B is the same as B < A

In JS, functions are objects. If you reeeeeally need it as a parameter, you can just pass it in.

I suggest you should use "console.log" to show the value of variable playerSelection, and computerSelection in the console.

const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
const playerSelection = getPlayerChoice();

let playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {

You have used the name playerSelection twice, and same for computerSelection. Any code inside of playRound will only be interacting with the parameter to the function, not with the global variable. Using the same variable name like this is called "variable shadowing", and is often a mistake.
So if you called playRound like this:
playRound('hello', 'world') 

Then code inside playRound will see playerSelection equals 'hello'. If you call it like this:
playRound()

Then playerSelection will be undefined.

To fix this, decide if you need the function arguments or not. If you do, make sure you pass the correct values in when you call it. I'd also recommend renaming the variables so there's no ambiguity about which variable is being accessed by the code inside playRound.
// variables renamed to avoid ambiguity
const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
const playerChoice = getPlayerChoice();

let playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {
  // ... same code as before, using playerSelection and computerSelection
}

playRound(computerChoice, playerChoice);

If you do not need function arguments, and you just want to use the global constants, then delete the parameters for the function
let playRound = () => {
  // ...
}
playRound() // no arguments needed, since they'll be ignored anyway

